# asp.net membercontrols Instruction text property in ChangePasswordTemplate

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I want to do the following in my page_load:

```
if (condition)
ChangePasswordControl.InstructionText = "......";
```

However, I am using a ChangePasswordTemplate which when generated doesn't include an 
`<asp:Literal ID="InstructionText runat="server" />` or similar.

Can anyone suggest how to conditionally include instructions in the template in this context?

Thanks, 
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not manually add a literal control into the template? You should then be able to  access it by doing something like this:

```
  Literal iText = ChangePassword1.ChangePasswordTemplateContainer.FindControl("myInstructionText") as Literal;
iText.Text = "This is my error message";
```